# Add a new Subordinate CA on a single ROOT CA environment

Tags: windows, active-directory, certificate-authority

I'll have an ROOT CA that is already joined to an Active Directory, this one has been serving certificates to the Joined Computers.
Now we want to add a subordinate/intermediate CA to deploy new certificates. And when certificates will be replaced the move Root CA to offline.

We now how to setup an Intermediate CA.
But the problem is that we are not sure how to move the role of the ROOT Ca that was configured to granting Certificates to the new Intermediate CA.
Do we need to change some configuration settings in ADSIedit that reflects this change of roles?

And how the target computers will know that should request certificate to the Intermediate instead to the Root?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a conversion from an Enterprise Root CA to Standalone. Not sure if that's what you want, but if you just want to have it mostly offline, keep it off and turn it on monthly for updates on a separate VLAN.  And this: `how the target computers will know that should request certificate to the Intermediate instead to the Root?` Sounds like hosts that already have certificates issued by the root?

Comment: Yes, the current Root is already issuing certificates. And the goal of this transformation adding an intermediate is put the Root separate and offline.